# Getting "IIS Detailed Error - 404.0" in Node.js webserver log even all resources are accessible

Tags: node.js, iis, azure, express

A web page hosted on Node.js server in Azure cloud displays the page *correctly* (confirmed with browser console), but Azure webserver console stil creates/logs detailed error pages for various "missing" files (js, ico, css, ttf...).

Example error page in server console (from `azure site log tail <site>`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>IIS Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found</title>
...
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;http://servername:80/js/ripples.min.js</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D:\home\site\wwwroot\js\ripples.min.js</td></tr> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr> 

</table>
...
```

How can I "fix" IIS not to raise/log these false positives?

Comment: What is _"missing"_ file?

Comment: @laika, as seen from error page in the log, one of those is `ripples.min.js`. As I said, IIS reports them as 404, but all are accessible (and rendered) on the web page.

Comment: @Saran I am seeing the same problem. I'm using a node.js rest api and it is showing web page data. what did you do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by disabling 'Detailed Error Messages' in the Azure website configuration:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but that is a workaround, not a solution. I want to see the error messages, but the reported error messages are **false** -- that is the problem.